# Keras' fit_generator extra training value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                    rescale=1./255,
                    shear_range=0.1,
                    zoom_range=0.1,
                    rotation_range=5.,
                    width_shift_range=0.1,
                    height_shift_range=0.1)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                    train_data_dir,
                    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
                    batch_size = 20,
                    shuffle = True,
                    classes = TYPES,
                class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                    val_data_dir,
                    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                    batch_size=20,
                    shuffle = True,
                    classes = TYPES,
                    class_mode = 'categorical')

model.fit_generator(
                train_generator,
                samples_per_epoch = 2000,
                nb_epoch = 20
            )

Epoch 14/50
 480/2000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 128s - loss: 0.8708

Epoch 13/50
2021/2000 [==============================] - 171s - loss: 0.7973 - acc: 0.7041
```

My ImageGenerators reading 2261 training and 567 testing images from folder. I am trying to train my model with 2000 samples_per_epoch and 20 batch_size. Batch_size is divisible for samples_per_epoch but somehow it is adding extra value and shows that warning:

> ( UserWarning: Epoch comprised more than `samples_per_epoch` samples,
>   which might affect learning results. Set `samples_per_epoch` correctly
>   to avoid this warning).

It works with Single-Gpu but If I try to train
with Multi-Gpus it gives that error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes:
>   [21] vs. [20]      [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]   [[Node: gradients/concat_25_grad/Slice_1/_10811 =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_101540_gradients/concat_25_grad/Slice_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1"]]

I am using that [code](https://github.com/kuza55/keras-extras/blob/master/utils/multi_gpu.py) for model parallelization:

Thanks for your help...

Comment: How many GPUs do you have?

Comment: I have 4xK80 GPUs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of training data must be equal samples_per_epoch ×　batch_size.
Please make the number of training data to 2260 by reducing one piece of data.
steps_per_epoch=113
batch_size=20

Answer (score 0):

try  change  samples_per_epoch  to  your_train_data.shape[0]

Comment: do you mean number of image count in training data? like  2261? it isn't divisible to batch size

Comment: you can try first

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there are 4 GPUs and while the training set is NOT divisible by 4 (number of GPU), 2261 /4 =565.25. The best is to make the training set divisible by 4 * 20 (# of GPU * Batch_size). Since the code uses data parallelism for the multiple GPU, it cannot be split the training set equally among 4 GPUs. Try to make your training and validation sets divisible by 4.

This is true for validation, and predication as well. You cannot let one or more GPUs idle while the other GPUs are working.

That's also why single CPU worked, since there is no training data division needed.